# SVN: Create a second repository

Tags: svn, url, repository, root

my problem is that the recent SVN URL points direktly to the repository "repo1" and not to the svn server root directory:

> svn://svnhost:3690 ===> "/svnroot/repo1/"

But now I have a second repository ("repo2"):

> /svnroot/repo1(/www/final_trunk)
>   /svnroot/repo2

How can I tell the svn server to point to the root directory "/svnroot"?

And what do I need to do to not again checkout out the whole repository just because of the new URL?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

update your server to use the new directory (however you have it configured, if svnserve, look to the .conf file)

To update your working copy to point to the new repo.. it's tricky becuase you've changed the repository contents, but look into [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) with or without the relocate option  to update your WC to correctly reference the repo.

Comment: Thx for your answers. Our setup doesn't run behind an apache I think it was setup like this "svnserve --root=/svnroot/repo1/ --listen-port=3690". Is this the same way how I can change the root dir again? And can I undo this if something goes wrong? When the server needs to be restarted, will the stetting still be there?

Answer (score 1):

In my setup I use svn behind Apache, and assign svn directories (given by `SVNPath` and `SVNParentPath`) to URLs using `<Location>` tag.

Further reading: [svnbook - httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)